# VueJS - How to register custom elements <v-form>, <v-checkbox>, <v-select>, <v-text-field>

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I'm new to VueJS. I've created a project using vuetify/webpack-ssr template, now I want to create a login page, however the forms aren't displayed and the console gives me the following:

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <v-form> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <v-text-field> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <v-select> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <v-checkbox> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

I am using these elements in my login form. Other Vue elements works perfectly except these items. How do I register these elements?

Here is my main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import {
  Vuetify,
  VApp,
  VNavigationDrawer,
  VFooter,
  VList,
  VBtn,
  VIcon,
  VGrid,
  VToolbar,
  VCard,
  transitions
} from 'vuetify'
import '../node_modules/vuetify/src/stylus/app.styl'
import App from './App.vue'
import Components from 'components/_index'

import { createStore } from 'store/index'
import { createRouter } from 'router/index'
import { sync } from 'vuex-router-sync'

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  components: {
    VApp,
    VNavigationDrawer,
    VFooter,
    VList,
    VBtn,
    VIcon,
    VGrid,
    VToolbar,
    VCard,
    transitions
  },
  theme: {
    primary: '#ee44aa',
    secondary: '#424242',
    accent: '#82B1FF',
    error: '#FF5252',
    info: '#2196F3',
    success: '#4CAF50',
    warning: '#FFC107'
  }
})
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: just import the elements from Vuetify, like `import {VForm} from "vuetify"; ` and put them in `Vue.use(Vuetify, { components: { VForm } })`

Comment: @DakshMiglani I have no idea that you can do that, I've read similar issues and not one answered as specific as this, thank you very much :D

Comment: np, keep asking questions on stack overflow whenever you've a problem. Somebody will be always there to help specific to ur use case!

Comment: That'd be a huge help for me :D thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not imported and defined the components that you are using and hence they are shown as warning.

Edit your code as below and everything should work fine.

```
 import Vue from 'vue'
    import {
      Vuetify,
      VApp,
      VForm,
      VTextField,
      VSelect,
      VCheckbox,
      VNavigationDrawer,
      VFooter,
      VList,
      VBtn,
      VIcon,
      VGrid,
      VToolbar,
      VCard,
      transitions
    } from 'vuetify'
    import '../node_modules/vuetify/src/stylus/app.styl'
    import App from './App.vue'
    import Components from 'components/_index'

    import { createStore } from 'store/index'
    import { createRouter } from 'router/index'
    import { sync } from 'vuex-router-sync'

    Vue.use(Vuetify, {
      components: {
        VApp,
        VForm,
        VTextField,
        VSelect,
        VCheckbox,
        VNavigationDrawer,
        VFooter,
        VList,
        VBtn,
        VIcon,
        VGrid,
        VToolbar,
        VCard,
        transitions
      },
      theme: {
        primary: '#ee44aa',
        secondary: '#424242',
        accent: '#82B1FF',
        error: '#FF5252',
        info: '#2196F3',
        success: '#4CAF50',
        warning: '#FFC107'
      }
    })
```

Comment: This is a lot better than what I have done (imported each elements) XD. I'm such a noob.

Comment: Thank you @Riddhi for putting my comment into a great answer. I'll upvote!